# Self-tracking entity Remove child entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

What is the right way to delete collection element from STE. Currently I use the following code:

```
order.Items[i].MarkAsDeleted();
order.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

Looks like it works (and ApplyChanges removes entity in spite I have removed it from collection). But it looks a bit ugly. Am I doint it right? Or may be there are other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is taken directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx):

> The MarkAsDeleted method changes the
>   state of the entity to Deleted. This
>   method also clears the navigation
>   properties on the entity that is being
>   marked for deletion. The navigation
>   property is set to null if it is
>   pointing to a reference object. The
>   Clear method is called if the
>   navigation property represents a
>   collection. When MarkAsDeleted is
>   called on an object that is part of a
>   collection, the object is removed from
>   the collection. To mark each object in
>   a collection as deleted, mark the
>   objects in a copy of the collection.
>   To get the copy of the collection,
>   call the ToArray() or ToList() method
>   on the collection, as in the following
>   example:

```
List<Course> courses = department.Courses.ToList();
foreach (var c in courses)
{
    // Mark each course in the department as Deleted.
    c.MarkAsDeleted();
}
```

So you are not doing it wrong because once you mark item as deleted it should be already removed from the `Items` collection so removing item at index will most probably remove break relation with another one.